# Visual Studio Brush Background color set

Tags: visual-studio, colors, win-universal-app

I am trying to change the color of the button in my Universal App.
This is the line:

```
Button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b));
```

But i get the error saying 'Color' does not exist in current context...
Do i need to include something or?

Comment: `Color` is declared in System.Windows.Media, so make sure that namespace is available.

Comment: System.Windows.Media, Media does not exist (Probably because i am running Windows Universal App)... I have tried just Windows.Media but the Color still isn't working.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that this was a Universal App.  It looks like the UA version is in Windows.UI according to msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Next time when this error occurred, you can click the wrong code and VS will suggest you to do some work. Usually when a reference is missed, you can just click the suggestion to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Color` is declared in `Windows.UI;`